# How to enable Line6 POD HD500x driver on Mac OS X

Tags: audio, mac

As I am new to the Apple OS X, I struggled installing the Line6 driver on my Mac.

The installation showed success, but after restarting I could not use the connected device, no additional input or output device was shown.

How can I enable the driver to work?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could see the problem in the Setup / Security tab. The OS tells you that the Line6 driver is not yet enabled due to security considerations. I had to push the enable button and it worked!